# TravisCI Ruby project not working with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, travis-ci

I have a Logstash plugin written in Ruby that has started failing on TravisCI, but it works locally.  Any ideas what this means?

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec

The signal EXIT is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Coverage may be inaccurate; set the "--debug" command line option, or do JRUBY_OPTS="--debug" or set the "debug.fullTrace=true" option in your .jrubyrc

W, [2016-12-02T14:12:20.127000 #5894]  WARN -- :       This usage of the Code Climate Test Reporter is now deprecated. Since version

      1.0, we now require you to run `SimpleCov` in your test/spec helper, and then

      run the provided `codeclimate-test-reporter` binary separately to report your

      results to Code Climate.

      More information here: https://github.com/codeclimate/ruby-test-reporter/blob/master/README.md

The command "bundle exec rspec spec" exited with 1.
```

From here:

https://travis-ci.org/mikebski/logstash-filter-datepart

Answer (score 5):

As you can see on the [code-climate/ruby-test-reporter CHANGELOG](https://github.com/codeclimate/ruby-test-reporter/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v100-2016-11-03), you need to replace these lines on your test helper file (in my case `spec/spec_helper.rb`):

```
require 'codeclimate-test-reporter'
CodeClimate::TestReporter.start
```

for these ones:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

Henceforth, you also have to call `codeclimate-test-reporter` explicitly.

Hope it helps!